# What is the behavior for referencing javascript libraries multiple times across multiple files?

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript files that I want to live independently of each other.  Each of these files reference other files for some library functionality.

Finally, there are times when all of this code can be used at the same time. I know that referencing a javascript file is not equivalent to a c++ include or java import.  Is there a way to achieve that kind of behavior?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Improving Javascript Load Times - Concatenation vs Many + Cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707499/improving-javascript-load-times-concatenation-vs-many-cache)

Comment: can you put some rough protoype of js files n explain the expected output with code.

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons you probably should concatenate them all into one. Compress that one using Google Closure and then serve it as a single **and cacheable** file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any native interface specification in Javascript. You "only" need to make sure the things you reference/access are already loaded. This may become messy if there are lots of dependencies.
That's why big JS-frameworks have some code for module loading and dependency specification.
Libraries I would name here are head.js and RequireJS.
But think what size of tool you really need.