# how to prevent the same fetches of img src when the same component is remounting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, fetch

Lets say we have the component that is mounted and unmounted N times. I'm using this component for background in other components so I cant escape mounting multiple times.

On every mount a  request is fetched to the server `window.API_BASE_URL` for the `camera${config.activeCameraId}.jpg`.
Which causes the component to blink for a sec until the img url is fully loaded.

```
const imgBackgroundComponent = (props) => {
// state logic
      const defaultCameraImageURL = `${window.API_BASE_URL}resources/images/camera${config.activeCameraId}.jpg`;
      return <div
            className={'image-wrapper'}
            key={cameraImage}
            style={{
                width: cameraImageSize.Width, // full image width
                height: cameraImageSize.Height, // full image height
                transform: `scale(${scale}) rotate(${rotate}deg) translateX(${pan.x}px) translateY(${pan.y}px)`,
                backgroundImage: `url(${defaultCameraImageURL})`,
                backgroundRepeat: `no-repeat`,
                backgroundPositionX: `${frameImgSrcBase64 && config.activeCameraId < cameraRowsCols.cols ? -cameraImageSize.Width * config.activeCameraId : 0}px`
            }}/>
}
```

Im looking for a way to save the img once fetched from the server and maybe store it in a singleton, which I did using base64 string. But the images are large and doing operations with the base64 (like zoom pan rotate) is kinda laggy. What can i do to store the image once fetched form the server in order to load fast on component mount.

Comment: I think browser caches it automatically. If you see the response it will 304 from the second time onwards

Comment: It's always 200

Comment: then you should allow the caching. Usually assets are cached by browser for a period of time.  check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19478438/304-not-modified-with-200-from-cache/48075133