# Handle 304 from my WS - promise response is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-status-code-304

Info : using AngularJS v1.3.15

> EDIT : this issue seems more related to how to handle a 304 response
>   from my webserver rather than ng-file-upload. I change title

I'm trying to manage 304 callback from my webserver and I have the following issue :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at ng-file-upload.js:79
    at angular.min.js:112
    at n.$get.n.$eval (angular.min.js:126)
    at n.$get.n.$digest (angular.min.js:123)
    at n.$get.n.$apply (angular.min.js:126)
    at l (angular.min.js:81)
    at M (angular.min.js:85)
    at XMLHttpRequest.F.onload (angular.min.js:86)
```

Line 79 of ng-file-upload.js is the following :

```
promise.success = function (fn) {
    promise.then(function (response) {
       console.log(response,config); // HERE RESPONSE IS UNDEFINED
        fn(response.data, response.status, response.headers, config);
    });
    return promise;
};
```

My code  to upload is the following : 
This code works well when my WebService sends a 200 response.

```
       Upload.upload({
            url: $localStorage.endPointVersion + "sky/!/avatar",
            fields: {},
            file: file
        }).progress(function (evt) {
            var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
            console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.file.name);
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('file ' + config.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ', data);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log('error ' + config.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + data);
        });
```

When file already exists on webServer,then, my webservices sends a 304 response.

So far, I have developped some interceptors and saw that 304 is indeed processed into responseError.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$location', '$injector', '$q', function($location, $injector, $q) {
                         return {
                            'responseError': function(rejection) {
                                 $log = $log || $injector.get('$log');

                                  if (rejection.status === 304) {
                                     // I have tried to reject it to go into error of upload, without success
                                     return $q.reject(rejection);

                                 }
                             }
                         };
                     }]);
```

**First question : Is this response code normal ? correct ? if not, what shall be an appropriate response to handle a "no change / not modified" POST ? Changing on Webserver from 304 response to another is possible but has huge impacts. If possible, I'd like to prevent changing that and manange on webapp 304 response properly**
**Second question (and the principal) : How shall I manage this 304 response from my Webserver ?**

I have seen that point :
[$http returns error when response is 304 (Not Modified) in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368969/http-returns-error-when-response-is-304-not-modified-in-angularjs) saying that angular valid status are  `return 200 <= status && status < 300;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up changing my backend response to handle differently the code status.

This question is solved.