# Why does this request return a 200(from cache) yet others return 304?

Tags: html, css, node.js, caching, frontend

Well I'm working on browser cache and write a node http server to help me learn, I used both cache-control and last-modified. Then enter this url in Chrome, and I simply press F5 to see if  caching works .Finally the result seems a little strange . 
[one return 200 and the others return 304 as excepted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCOVp.png)

Intro_1.jpg was loaded by style.css (`background-image:url(../images/intro_1.jpg`); )
So why this request return a 200(from cache) yet others return 304? 
Is that correct?

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**, 200 vs 304 status codes always depend on whether the resource has "expired". You are correct, a status code of 200 means from the cache - no HTTP request was made - that's why you see *From Memory Cache* in DevTools. A status code of 304 means the cache entry had expired and the browser had no choice but to make a HTTP request to ask server if any changes have been made. The server returning a status code of 304 is a way of it telling the browser that it does not need to download a new version of the resource and it can keep using the same cache entry.

More: [What is the difference between HTTP status code 200 (cache) vs status code 304?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665082/what-is-the-difference-between-http-status-code-200-cache-vs-status-code-304)

Each resource has its own timeout value so it is possible that some
will expire while others will not. You should check the HTTP responses in DevTool -- in the *Network* tab, click a request and on the right-hand side, click *Response*. You can see the expiry values the server gave to the browser. Check if the resources have different `max-age`, or if they have different `last-modified`. I'm sure that in this case, it does not matter that the jpg was in a CSS file.