# Browser may not use cache

Tags: javascript, angular, caching, webpack, browser

I'm using Webpack 4 and I'm in Hot Module Replacement mode while using Webpack devServer.

For some reason, chrome keeps downloading the bundles even when I'm using hashes.

The output:

```
Hash: 23594d99dc21755c5643
Version: webpack 4.17.1
Time: 1901ms
Built at: 2018-08-30 08:48:18
                           Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
        a17719b06f0064365b32.css   35 bytes       0  [emitted]  main
0.210b787809a8d87a8b98.bundle.js  501 bytes       0  [emitted]  main
1.640168cdfaffafd85d00.bundle.js    111 KiB       1  [emitted]  vendors~main
  ff4dc475b068a1649cf3.bundle.js   1.43 KiB       2  [emitted]  runtime
                      index.html  417 bytes          [emitted]
Entrypoint main = ff4dc475b068a1649cf3.bundle.js 1.640168cdfaffafd85d00.bundle.js a17719b06f0064365b32.css 0.210b787809a8d87a8b98.bundle.js
[60] ./src/main.css 39 bytes {0} [built]
[62] ./src/index.js + 1 modules 765 bytes {0} [built]
     | ./src/index.js 97 bytes [built]
     | ./src/component.js 643 bytes [built]
    + 61 hidden modules
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = index.html
    [2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 489 bytes {0} [built]
    [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {0} [built]
        + 2 hidden modules
Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/index.js!src/main.css:
    Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
    [0] ./node_modules/css-loader!./src/main.css 194 bytes {0} [built]
        + 1 hidden module
```

After clearing cache from chrome:
[image]
After a second refresh without clearing the cache:
[image]

**My questions:**

1. Why are the bolded (yellow) bundles not loaded from disk cache?
2. What are the `localhost` and `ng-validate.js` files? (I don't have any angular dependencies).

---

Link to my playground-project: https://github.com/stavalfi/webpack-demo

Comment: They are loaded from the cache as the file is not modified. (304 status code suggests this as well as the small file size)

Comment: Then why `ng-validate` is specified as loaded `from disk cache` and the rest are not?

Comment: That should be because ng-validate saying it is cachable on the initial response. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1665097/3156644

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome does not re-download those files. But it has to make a request to ensure that the file has not changed. The response status is 304('Not Modified'). The request still takes a few bytes to go and check for file changes.

`ng-validate.js` is called from 'content-script' suggesting that it could be called from an extension. You can check this by visiting the same page with all extensions disabled (or in incognito mode.)